# Cos x bounded by $x$-axis. Find k given information about k.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the part of the graph of $y = \cos x$ between $x= -\pi/2$ and $x=\pi/2$ is separated into two regions by the line $x=k$. If the area of the region for $-\pi/2$ is less than or equal to $x$ which is less than or equal to k is three times the area of the region for $k$ is less than or equal to $x$ which is less than or equal to $\pi/2$, then $k=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. The area under the curve $y=\cos x$, and above the $x$-axis, from $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $x=k$ is
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^k \cos x\,dx.\tag{1}$$
The area from $x=k$ to $x=\pi/2$ is
$$\int_k^{\pi/2} \cos x\,dx.\tag{2}$$
The first area is $3$ times the second. Thus
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^k \cos x\,dx=3\int_{k}^{\pi/2} \cos x\,dx.$$
Do the integrations. The integral (1) is $1+\sin k$, and the integral (2) is $1-\sin k$.
Thus $1+\sin k=3(1-\sin k)$. It follows that $\sin k=\frac{1}{2}$ and therefore $k=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: how did you determine that the cos(-pi/2) was 1? wouldn't it be negative one?

Comment: Calculate $\int_{-\pi/2}^k \cos x\,dx$. An antiderivative is $\sin x$. So we compute $\sin k -(\sin(-\pi/2))$. But $\sin(-\pi/2)=-1$, so we get $\sin k-(-1)$, which is $\sin (k)+1$, or, more attractively, $1+\sin k$.

Comment: Then how did you determine that sin k= 1/2?

Comment: I gave the equation $1+\sin k=3(1-\sin k)$. Expand to $1+\sin k=3-3\sin k$. Rearrange. We get $4\sin k=2$, and therefore $\sin k=2/4=1/2$.